# AJAX hiddenfield submit instead of form does not work

Tags: html, jquery, asp.net, ajax

I have trouble sending AJAX post request to controller. The following code works:

```js
var path = $(this).prop("value");

                    var token = $('[name=__RequestVerificationToken]').val();
                    var headers = {};
                    headers["__RequestVerificationToken"] = token;

                    var ids = $("#ids").val();

                    
                    var formData = new FormData();
                    formData.append('ids', ids);


                    $.ajax({
                        url: path,
                        type: "POST",
                        cache: false,
                        headers: headers,
                        data: formData,
                        async: false,
                        processData: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        success: function (result) {
                            document.write(result);
                            document.close();
                            console.log("YES");
                        },
                        error: function () {
                            alert("Error.");
                            
                        }
                    });
```

Here is the Controller Method:

```cs
    [AjaxOnly]
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Location = OutputCacheLocation.None)]
        public ActionResult MyMethod(string aString)
```

The call to the Controller works fine, but as expected `aString` in Controller-Function parameter is null.

What I actually want to do is not to POST the `formData` `($("#myForm").serialize();)` in the data field of the AJAX post, but an *hiddenField*:

```js
    var aString = $("#ids").val();
```

So when I put the `aString` variable in the data field of Ajax call instead of `formData` the call to my function does not work anymore and I get *500* error.

Anyone can help how to POST this `hiddenfield` value instead of `formData`?

MyForm:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "MyForm";
    @model MyFormModel
}
@using (Html.BeginForm("MyForm", "MyController", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "MyForm" }))
{
 <div class="tab-content" id="tabContent">
content
</div>
   @Html.Partial("_MyFormPopup")
```

Partial:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("MyMethod", "MyController", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
 <div class="modal fade">
content
</div>
  @Html.Hidden("ids")
```

Controller Code:

```
    [AjaxOnly]
            [HttpPost]
            [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
            [OutputCache(NoStore = true, Location = OutputCacheLocation.None)]
            public ActionResult MyMethod(string ids)
            {
               
    
                string[] IdsFunktions = ids.Split(new string[] { ";" }, 
    
                ....
     return RedirectToAction("MyForm");
}
```

Comment: In order to help we need the actual `<form>` HTML code to see how are your fields being defined.

Comment: Can you add it again after the question edit? I cannot see it.

Comment: Now you should see it. It did not saved properly.

Comment: When you post request `formData` as $("#myForm").serialize();, the controller variable should be referenced by `ids` not `aString`, but can you post your code when you want to send only the `aString` JS variable, how are you posting it with JavaScript?

Comment: So when i rename aString to ids it should work ? i posting with jquery.

Comment: Can you also post the controller code where you read the posted variables data?

Comment: Added Controller Code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in order for your code to work you need to correctly name your `formData` variables, here are the two variants:

If you want to have a `aString` variable on your Controller then your AJAX post code should post like this:

```js
var formData = new FormData();
formData.append('aString', $("#ids").val());

$.ajax({
  url: path,
  type: "POST",
  cache: false,
  headers: headers,
  data: formData,
  async: false,
  success: function (result) {
    document.write(result);
    document.close();      
  },
  error: function () {
    alert("Error.");
  }
});
```

---

**Another solution** would be in the case you want to post **all form fields** data by using `data: $("#myForm").serialize()` you must change the Controller reference variable names and reference each field by its form name, e.g if you have only one hidden field then:

```cs
[AjaxOnly]
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[OutputCache(NoStore = true, Location = OutputCacheLocation.None)]
public ActionResult MyMethod(string ids, string fieldNameOne, string fieldNameTwo, etc...)
```

Comment: Yes. That is exactly my problem. I changed the controller reference to aString. After that i get an 500 error. When i debug i can see that the post did not reach the controller method. When i change it back to formData the call works, but the values are null.

Comment: What is the value of the hidden `#ids` field? Can you post an example value? E.g extract it from the browser inspector.

Comment: Value is: D_75295

Comment: I've edited my answer to specify the correct way of composing `formData`, it is not JSON but rather the default `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format.